# Select previous 5 tweets based on one timestamp

Tags: r, time, difference

I have a `tweets` table that looks like this:

```
tweet_id          tweet_text       user_id    created_at
1 6.127048e+17      asfasfadsfdas       1       2015-06-21 16:33:13
2 6.128451e+17      adsgfasdgg          1       2015-06-22 15:33:13
4 6.132484e+17      adgfdasgfadg        2       2015-06-20 17:33:13
5 6.132562e+17      adgfdagfdag         2       2015-06-19 18:33:13
6 6.132867e+17      adgfdagfdhgfd       3       2015-06-21 19:33:13
```

I also have a similar table called `allTweets`, which includes all the tweets from all the users. It has these columns:

```
tweet_id          tweet_text       user_id    created_at
```

I want to loop over `tweets$tweet_id` and find the previous 5 tweets from `allTweets` which belongs to the corresponding `user_id`.

For example, the first tweet in `tweets` belongs to `user_id 1` and was created_at 2015-06-21 16:33:13. I have to find out the previous 5 tweets which belongs to `user_id 1` from `allTweets` based on this timestamp.

Comment: Are you essentially looking for the latest 5 tweets from all the unique user_id's in "tweets"? Asking because it looks like one user_id can appear multiple times in "tweets".

Comment: No. Since one user can have multiple tweets in table "tweets", which have different created time, I need to look for the previous 5 tweets based on its created time from the same user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me reiterate my understanding of what you are asking. You need to:

1. Iterate over each row of table "tweets" (which I am assuming is a
   dataframe).
2. For every row, check the user_id and the created_at
       time.
3. Then go to table "allTweets" and for the particular user_id, find out the top 5 tweets that are just earlier than the time given by "created_at" for that user in step 2.

Here's one way to go about this:

1. Split dataframe tweets based on user_id.

   `tweetsList <- split(tweets, tweets$user_id)`

This should get your data in this format:

```
$1  
[1] tweet_id          tweet_text       created_at  
1 6.127048e+17      asfasfadsfdas      2015-06-21 16:33:13  
2 6.128451e+17      adsgfasdgg         2015-06-22 15:33:13  

$2
[1] tweet_id          tweet_text       created_at
4 6.132484e+17      adgfdasgfadg       2015-06-20 17:33:13
5 6.132562e+17      adgfdagfdag        2015-06-19 18:33:13
```

2. Now, for each list element, you need to find the top 5 entries from
   dataframe allTweets that are just smaller than the respective values
   of "created_at" variable.

   -Sort allTweets data frame by "created_at" column.
       * `allTweets <- allTweets[order(allTweets$created_at)]`

   -Define a function that takes a vector as input and returns the 5 entries that we need from allTweets.
       * `gimme5 <- function(x){tail(allTweets[x["created_at"] > allTweets$created_at, ])}`

   -Since this function only works on vectors, and our list is a list of dataframes, we will need to progressively subset and apply on each row of our dataframes.
       * `apply(*dataframe*, 1, gimme5) #*dataframe* is for each component dataframe in our list`

   -Finally, we will want to apply our previous command for each dataframe component of our list. Thus, we want to apply it to tweetsList[["1"]], tweetsList[["2"]] etc. This will generate the *dataframe* component of the code above.
       * lapply(tweetsList, function(x) apply(x, 1, gimme5))